# Save data in octave

Tags: octave

In Octave, I have `x=-13:0.1:13`

then, I save as:
`save file.dat x`

and when I open file.dat I get:

```
 -13
 -12.9
 -12.8
 -12.7
 -12.6
 -12.5
 -12.4
 -12.3
 -12.2
 -12.1
 -12
 -11.9
 -11.8
 -11.7
 -11.6
 -11.5
 -11.4
 -11.3
 -11.2
 -11.1
 -11
 -10.9
 -10.8
 -10.7
 -10.6
 -10.5
 -10.4
 -10.3
 -10.2
 -10.1
 -10
 -9.9
 -9.800000000000001
 -9.699999999999999
 -9.6
 -9.5
 -9.4
 -9.300000000000001
 -9.199999999999999
 -9.1
 -9
 -8.899999999999999
 -8.800000000000001
 -8.699999999999999
...
```

But I would like to save `-8.7`, and not `-8.699999999999999`; `-8.8` and not `-8.800000000000001`...

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what function you're using to write to the file, one way to fix the problem is specify the format with single digit precision.

For example:

```
fprintf(fid, "%4.1f", x(i));
```

writes x(i) to fid with 1 digit after the decimal.

Comment: you can just pass a vector in which case it will repeat the template for all entries, e.g., just do `printf ("%4.1f\n", 0:.1:3)`

Comment: Thanks so much Alex B and carandraug. Very useful!